# How can I run a slash-wean project?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate a slush wean project.I've created a new folder : mkdir test and then run slash wean .After installing I tried to run gukp run ,but it shows me this error:

```
Invalid value for 'app.urls[0]'.Missing scheme separator.
```

I tried this solution : change the line in package.json with this :

```
"node-remote": "http://<local>"
```

Now when I run gulp run it freezes the terminal with the message :Lauching App.

Can you help me fixing it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the server port defined in app/app.js

```
"http://<local>:3000"
```